# Prestashop 1.6.11 front office not found in a local environement

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, server-migration

I had to work on a project made with prestashop 1.6.11 , and i tried to put it in my local web server (wamp).

But i just have an access to the back-office panel and the front office isn't find
(It's return a 404 error).

I have changed my configuration table in my database (more particularly PS_SHOP_DOMAIN and PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL ),and the pre7666_SHOP_URL .
I also changed the file settings.inc.php with my new database informations.

If anyone had the same problem , and fixed it , i'm open to all proposals that you can send.

Thank you in advance

Comment: **"I follow many tutorial about prestashop migration without any good results."** is useless. Write exactly which methods have you tried.

Comment: Have you changed the value in ps_shop_url table?

Comment: yes i did it , but nothing has changed

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to regenerate the .htaccess file located in your root folder.

You can regenerate the .htaccess file by clicking the save button in the "Seo & URLs" menu in your back-office.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove .htaccess file from root directory